# How do I specify signingConfigs for different product variants with flavor dimensions?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-flavordimension

This has been asked before (e.g. [Gradle signing with flavors and dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563543/gradle-signing-with-flavors-and-dimensions)), but the answers don't seem to work with Gradle 3.5.

With 2 flavor dimensions I'm specifying signingConfigs per release variant like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    klondikeGoogleRelease
    ...
    pyramidGoogleRelease
    pyramidAmazonRelease
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavors = variant.productFlavors
    variant.mergedFlavor.setApplicationId flavors[0].ext.applicationId + flavors[1].ext.applicationIdSuffix

    if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        variant.mergedFlavor.setSigningConfig android.signingConfigs[variant.name]
    }
    println "Mergedflavor: ${variant.name} signing ${variant.signingConfig.name} ready ${variant.signingReady}"
}
```

This is enough for `gradle signingReport` to report the correct settings, but `gradle assemblePyramidGoogleRelease` (for example) will build an unsigned apk.

It's skipping the `validateSigningPyramidGoogleRelease` task, which is reflected in the results of the `gradle tasks --all` output, which doesn't list `validateSigning*` for any of the `*Release` variants.

Comment: I'm currently working through this issue myself.  Were you able to find a solution?  I'll post what I come up with once I find a viable option, but would love to hear if you had found a solution.

Comment: My current workaround is to set the signing config directly from the environment: `android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = android.signingConfigs[variantName]`. It's of course limited to one variant at a time, and doesn't work within Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

you can set signing config before package task

package task name display with you flavors and buldTypes

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.findByName("packageFlavorBuildType").doFirst {
        packageFlavorBuildType.setSigningConfig(signingConfigs.yourKeyConfig)
    }
}
```